# How to replace double space with one space (shorten space)

Tags: c++

This is what i have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userString.size(); i++) 
   {
      if(userString.at(i) && userString.at(i + 1) == ' ')
      {
       userString.replace(space, i);
      }
   }
```

I tried replacing the two index of spaces with one space by doing :

```
userString.at(i) && userString.at(i + 1) = ' ';
```

but that didn't seem to work (i am new to all of this)

Comment: You're trying to assign to a function call?

Comment: `userString.at(i) && userString.at(i + 1) == ' '` does not check both values to see if they are both spaces ...

Comment: @tadman yes i am

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Also `userString.at(i) && userString.at(i + 1) == ' '` doesn't check for equalty of both symbols to space, only for latter one. If you need to check both symbols use `userString.at(i) == ' ' && userString.at(i + 1) == ' '`.

Comment: Aso, if you increment `i` out to the end of the string, what's at index `i+1`?

Comment: ohhh i see i missed that thanks ! @fas